# How to model the StackOverflow website with DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I take the example of StackOverflow because obviously you know that website, and my real usecase is really close.

So let's imagine a simplified SO domain description:

- There are users
- Users can create new questions
- Users can create answers to these questions
- Users can edit their own questions and answers
- **Users can edit other users questions if they have more than 1000 reputation** (took that threshold randomly)

The last bold rule is the one that matters to me.

What I understand about an AggregateRoot is that it should contain the state that serves to take decision to accept or reject commands, and it should not query a DB to do so. It guarantees the consistency of the app. It should only listen to the events it emits to update its state.

Now what I think is that the SO domain has an aggregate root called Question.
That question would then handle commands like:

- CreateAnswer
- EditQuestion

The thing is, when the EditQuestion is fired, how the Question AggregateRoot would be able to decide wether to accept or refuse that command? Because if you remember, the command should be rejected if you try to edit the question of another user if you have < 1000 reputation.

It does not seem to make sens to me that the Question AR maintain a list of all users reputations, to be able to know how to act on that command.

The problem is that when trying to model my domain I have this modeling problem coming over and over again, and I always end up with a single big fat AggregateRoot

Can someone tell me what I am missing and help me solve this problem? thanks

This [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/71847/with-all-of-these-services-how-can-i-not-be-anemic) seems to say that we should not put the authorization system inside the domain model. I agree this may be practical for things like role-based authentication. However, to me the "users can't edit unless they have enough reputation" is really an SO business rule, so how could it be outside of the domain?

**IMPORTANT: when answering, please consider YOU are the business expert**. You know StackOverflow as an user and can guess what are the SO constraints by yourself. Even if you are wrong about them, it's not a big deal: just make a proposal for your wrong business constraints I'm fine with that!!!

It's not the first time I ask this kind of question and it always ends up with no answer but just endless discussions. What I want to know is how you would model StackOverflow if you had to build this site, with a focus on the business rules about the minimum reputation to edit.

Comment: You can't always rely on strong consistency. Does it really matter if the user was at 1000 but then lost 50 reputation in the same second he was editing the question? What kind of business impact it really has?

Comment: It comes down to AR size but the bigger the aggregate the more contention you will have. As plalx rightly said would it really matter if the rep reduced? So check the user.Reputation property inside the question edit method (passing in a full user object). If you were very worried about this then a saga could be used to implemenent the edit commit as an external transaction(s) which will either complete or roll back and go to some known state and notifying relevant parties

Comment: @g18c Not even sure how this would be modeling using eventual consistency? Would you handle  `UserReputationChanged` events and then check if the user did modify a question after it's reputation dropped under some threshold. If it did then you would perform a compensating action on the question like undo the edit and notify the user? I guess you would also have to handle `QuestionEdited` events in case events come out of order?

Comment: Indeed. I agree with that train of thought. However if the business can accept the possibility of a users points dropping between start and end of edit then makes it far simpler

Comment: @SebastienLorber A decisive question for your design is, what is your policy regarding concurrent changes to a Q by users who have >1000 rep ? Last one wins ? Merge ? Optimistic locking ? etc.

Comment: @SebastienLorber No offense, but I think you don't realize how these domain insights are key to modelling your aggregates. You will end up with a completely different model depending if the business experts want immediate or eventual consistency, what concurrent access strategy they want for Q edition, etc.

Comment: @SebastienLorber Big fat aggregate root can be a problem indeed (not always), but the relevant solution to that depends primarily on what is acceptable or not business wise. I'm thinking about an answer but is difficult to come up with one without speculating about StackOverflow constraints and data we don't have (how many users with > 1000 rep are there ? How many edits to a Q on average ? etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, things are quite simple IMO (in this SO scenario only). This is how **I** would do it (obviously, other devs probably have different approaches):

You tagged the question well with the "cqrs". In the *EditQuestion* handler, I'd use a Domain Service (a Query from a CQRS point of view) which will check if a certain use has the required points and then return a true/false. Something like this (more or less pseudo code)

```
public class CanUserEditQuestionService
{
    //constructor with deps\\

    public bool Handle(CanUserEditQuestion input)
    {
       //query the read model, maybe a query object to get us the rep of the user
      var rep=getReputation.Get(input.UserId);

      //we can have a dependency here which tell us the number of points required for a specific permission

     return(rep>=1000);
    }
}
```

If the query returns true, then the handler will perform changes on the Question entity i.e question.ChangeText() or smth (I think SO takes an event sourcing approach).

What you have here is a simple use case of a concept "Question" , its command behaviour "Edit" and the business rule that dictates who can do what. The thing is, the 1000 rep rule is never part of the Question concept definition, therefore it doesn't belong to that aggregate i.e how the question is edited. However it's part of the use case itself and part of the application service.

I'm sure that you'll ask me : "What if the read model used by the domain query is behind the command model?". In this case it matters very little, the delay it's probably measured in seconds at most. Also the main thing here is: the business rule is not part of the Question aggregate so it doesn't care about being immediate consistent.

Another thing is that user rep is always a different concept than of a Question so dealing with rep should be never a part of a Question aggregate. But it is part of the application service.

If you view an application as a group of use cases doing things with concepts (which themselves encapsulate data and business constraints), it's quite easy to identify which is the application service, aggregate, domain service etc.

Comment: thanks for your answer. What I thought is that all business rules where supposed to be encoded in the domain (I mean in the Aggregates). So what I understand is that when we don't need immediate consitency and the rule involve multiple concepts, the business rule can be encoded outside of the Aggregate, is this what you mean?

Comment: Business rules are part of the domain but the aggregate cares only about the rules which ensure its (immediate) consistency, what the business sees as a whole, a unit. However, when implementing a use case, besides the aggregate there can be other domain behaviour implemented as domain services and required by the application service which the 'manager' of the use case. In the end part of the role of an application service is to take care of authorization, but the domain service contains the actual implementation.

Comment: Thanks it helps me a lot. By curiosity how would you do if for this usecase immediate consistency was a business requirement?

Comment: It all depends on the domain, but usually authorization is never part of an aggregate (because it's not part of a definition/consistency rules).

Comment: +1 @MikeSW, and based on your answer it seems that DDD will help prevent services bloat (too many services), but doesn't mean you will avoid services completely, just that there will be less (since you try to build Aggregates that are self consistent instead of tons of random domain services that you have to remember how to use them together). So is it safe to say that when you ask the question "where does this go? Doesn't make sense to go in an entity..." that is probably when you just need a domain service. Right? And in the end, DDD is just good OOP?

Comment: @prograhammer Actuallly, DDD is high level design, while OOP is one of the ways we can implement the design. Some people go for FP, I have a hybrid style, especially when ES is involved.

Comment: There's a fine line between pure authorization and domain rules. I agree that generic authorizations such as ACLs shouldn't be part of the domain, but the reputation-based system is core to the SO domain. The way it works and is balanced has a direct business impact. I do agree however that the check probably doesn't belong in the `Question` AR nor the `User` AR.

Comment: So what you mean @MikeSW is that if a Question is edited by the wrong person, somehow it does not make the Question aggregate inconsistent right?

Comment: @SebastienLorber You seem under the incorrect assumption that there *must* be a `User` aggregate and a `Question` aggregate. It is not the case. CQRS precisely frees us from that.

Comment: See this example about bank accounts where there is no Account aggregate : http://simon-says-architecture.com/2013/03/07/modelling-accounting-ledger-event-driven/

Comment: @guillaume31 I don't understand what you want to mean in the context of this discussion. If you see other possible aggregates here please tell me in your answers. Also I commented on the link you provided and I am interested by your thoughts on my comment.

Comment: I'm saying that I like that workflow better : 1/ define commands *, invariants and events*, 2/ ask domain expert what should be immediately consistent and what can be eventually consistent 3/ derive your Aggregates

Comment: That approach can lead you to a design that you'd never have thought of but that works. Instead of starting from preconceived aggregates that you *think* make sense.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach if you want immediate consistency

```cs
public class UserCommandHandler 
{
  public void Handle(EditQuestion command)
  {
    // (start transaction)
    var user = userRepository.Get(command.UserId);
    if (user.Reputation < 1000) 
      // reject command here
    var edit = user.EditedQuestion(...); // or just "new QuestionEdit(...)"
    questionEditRepository.Add(edit);
    // (commit, saving the QuestionEdited event)
  }
}
```

Since we're using CQRS, the state of a Question as reflected on a page would not be contained in an `Question` Aggregate but a projection of a series of `QuestionEdited` events that were listened to and cumulated over time.

Comment: Still not strongly consistent, unless `user.EditedQuestion` also modifies the `user` AR which would prevent `user` from being modified by another transaction.

Comment: @guillaume31 yes but you assume I can use a transactions over users and questions repositories at the same time which in practice is often not the case (or wanted) for scalability reasons.

Comment: (sorry I deleted my comment, what I really wanted to say is that, depending how you manage transactions, you don't have to modify `User` to get immediate consistency)

Comment: But you can also encapsulate QuestionEdits inside the User (or UserActivity) aggregate instead of giving it its own aggregate if you want.

Comment: @SebastienLorber Why "over users *and questions*" ?

Comment: Because you read/write both in the same transaction. Can you achieve that with MongoDB?

Comment: I have no idea. Your Q didn't mention MongoDB. I'm asking "why over users **and questions**" because I never said some `Question` aggregate came into play when you edit a question.